# How to extract the variables from a polynomial in python /Sage

Tags: python, function, sage

In mathematica I can write >Variables[x^2y+2z] and get {x,y,z}. Is there a similar function in Sage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
sage: var('x y z')
(x, y, z)
sage: expr = x^2*y + 2*z
sage: expr.variables()
(x, y, z)
```